# Correlation functions of XY quantum chain

Tags: quantum-spin, fermions, correlation-functions, spin-models, ground-state

I'm trying to understand the calculation of the correlation functions in the XY quantum chain performed by Lieb, Mattis and Schultz in the paper "Two Solvable Models of an antiferromagnetic chain" (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0003491661901154). But, i don't understand the following calculation for ground state of XY model:

$$ <B_{i}A_{j}> = \sum_{k,k'}\Psi_{k,i}\phi_{k',j}<(\eta_{k}^{\dagger}-\eta_{k})(\eta_{k'}^{\dagger}+\eta_{k'})> = \sum_{k,k'}\Psi_{k,i}\phi_{k',j}(<\eta_{k}^{\dagger}\eta_{k'}>-<\eta_{k}\eta_{k'}^{\dagger}>)=-\sum_{k}\Psi_{k,i}\phi_{k,j}$$

I think that the last passage was used the fact that the ground state is defined by
$$ \eta_{k}|GS> = 0$$ for ever k. Is it correct?

How would this calculation be for the case where the ground state is half-filled? As

$$ |GS> = \prod_{|k|<k_{F}}\eta_{k}^{\dagger}|0>$$.

Comment: Yes, therefore $\langle \eta_k^\dagger \eta_{k'}\rangle=0, \langle \eta_k\eta_{k'}^\dagger\rangle=\delta_{kk'}$.

Comment: I thank you @MengCheng. Do you know how I can extend this idea to a half-filled ground state? Because this property isn't true in this case. Or am I wrong?

Comment: $\langle \eta_k^\dagger \eta_{k'}\rangle=n_k\delta_{kk'}, \langle \eta_k\eta_{k'}^\dagger\rangle=(1-n_k)\delta_{kk'}$, where $n_k$ by definition is the occupation number of mode $k$. For half filled ground state, $n_k=1$ if $|k|<k_F$ and $0$ otherwise.